# Chrome Mobile version 43 (on Android) calculates touch events wrong when scroll left not 0

Tags: javascript, events, scroll, touch

Its not realy a question more like a Isuee Topic.
Currently I'm working on cross-browser/platform solution for my company and I noticed something wrong with the new 'Chrome Mobile' version (43).

Its seems that the Value provided on touch events is an absolute value that not consider the scroll position.

Explain in code:

#### Lets say the scroll-left position is 100px

#### And We trigger touch event on 200x200

#### On Chrome mobile version <= 42 the value will be 300

event.originalEvent.touches[0].pageX // value will be 300

#### On Chrome mobile version 43 the value will be 200

event.originalEvent.touches[0].pageX // value will be 200

Some one can validate that?

This data relay on testing of 4 android devices 4 on version 42/34 and 1 on version 43

Comment: Which Jquery libraries are you using and which versions ?

Comment: The scenario above happened on version **1.10.2**